# Is database optional for worklight server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have a question: for what purpose database is needed for Worklight server?

If it's for application center only (e.g. statistics, devices registrations, etc..), and I don't plan to use application center, can I avoid to use database?

Or if Workligth application needs the database (e.g. from what I heard - application's Adapters are registered in database) - then I must to use database always?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a database is required for when using Worklight, be it for adapters, push or SMS notifications, various authentication mechanisms, Application Center (separate database than for Worklight Server), etc.

Comment: Thanks for confirming